# Dio - QueuedInterceptor to handle Refresh Token with multiple requests

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am calling multiple api's like this

```
await Future.wait([profile, calendar, cities]);
```

I have a interceptor class which extends **Dio** **QueuedInterceptor**.
Say on profile api, my access token expires and `onError` gets called.
So I hit refresh_token api, I retry the current request, on success I call `handler.resolve(response);`. But the remaining api's still call the interceptor `onError` method and my refresh_token api is hit total 3 times.
What can be the issue?

```
    Future<void> onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      var tokenDio = Dio();

      try {
        Response refreshResponse = await tokenDio.post('/${endPoint.path}',
            data: endPoint.requestBody);

        if (refreshResponse.statusCode == 201) {
          var newAccessToken = refreshResponse.data['access_token'];

          var newHeaders = err.requestOptions.headers;
          newHeaders['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $newAccessToken';
          
           var response = await dio.request(
            err.requestOptions.path,
            data: err.requestOptions.data,
            queryParameters: err.requestOptions.queryParameters,
            options: Options(
              method: err.requestOptions.method,
              headers: newHeaders,
            ),
          );
          
          return handler.resolve(response);
        } 
        else {
          return handler.reject(err);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return handler.reject(err);
      }
    } 
    else {
      return handler.next(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a fix for it? I am having the same issue with my project.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution without extending `QueuedInterceptor` class in your interceptor:

1. Extend `Interceptor` class instead of `QueuedInterceptor` class.
2. Create a boolean `isRefreshing`, set it to true when the first request fails and send a `refreshToken` request to refresh your access token.
3. Create a list of failed requests, let all the requests fail and keep adding the failed requests to this list as long as `isRefreshing` is true.
4. Once the token is refreshed (Step 2), retry all failed requests by looping through the `failedRequests` list.

```
if (!isRefreshing) {
    debugPrint("ACCESS TOKEN EXPIRED, GETTING NEW TOKEN PAIR");
    isRefreshing = true;
    await refreshToken(err, handler);
} else {
    debugPrint("ADDING ERRRORED REQUEST TO FAILED QUEUE");
    failedRequests.add({'err': err, 'handler': handler});
}
```

Full code of the interceptor:

```
class MyHttpInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> failedRequests = [];
  bool isRefreshing = false;

  MyHttpInterceptor();

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    debugPrint('REQUEST[${options.method}] => PATH: ${options.path}');
    handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    debugPrint(
        'RESPONSE[${response.statusCode}] => PATH: ${response.requestOptions.path}');
    handler.next(response);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    debugPrint(
        'ERROR[${err.response?.statusCode}] => PATH: ${err.requestOptions.path}, IS REFRESHING: ${isRefreshing.toString()}');
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      if (getIt<AuthProvider>().refreshToken.isEmpty) {
        debugPrint("LOGGING OUT: NO REFRESH TOKEN FOUND");
        // perform logout
        return handler.reject(err);
      }

      if (!isRefreshing) {
        debugPrint("ACCESS TOKEN EXPIRED, GETTING NEW TOKEN PAIR");
        isRefreshing = true;
        await refreshToken(err, handler);
      } else {
        debugPrint("ADDING ERRRORED REQUEST TO FAILED QUEUE");
        failedRequests.add({'err': err, 'handler': handler});
      }
    } else {
      return handler.next(err);
    }
  }

  FutureOr refreshToken(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    Dio retryDio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: baseURI,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${getIt<AuthProvider>().refreshToken}'
        },
      ),
    );
    // handle refresh token
    var response = await retryDio.get('/user/get-at-by-rt');
    var parsedResponse = response.data;
    if (response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 403) {
      // handle logout
      debugPrint("LOGGING OUT: EXPIRED REFRESH TOKEN");
      return handler.reject(err);
    }

    // handle setting tokens in your store for future requests

    isRefreshing = false;
    failedRequests.add({'err': err, 'handler': handler});
    debugPrint("RETRYING ${failedRequests.length} FAILED REQUEST(s)");
    retryRequests(parsedResponse['data']['access_token']);
  }

  Future retryRequests(token) async {
    Dio retryDio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: baseURI,
      ),
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < failedRequests.length; i++) {
      debugPrint(
          'RETRYING[$i] => PATH: ${failedRequests[i]['err'].requestOptions.path}');
     RequestOptions requestOptions =
          failedRequests[i]['err'].requestOptions as RequestOptions;
      requestOptions.headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      };
      await retryDio.fetch(requestOptions).then(
            failedRequests[i]['handler'].resolve,
            onError: (error) =>
                failedRequests[i]['handler'].reject(error as DioError),
          );
    }
    isRefreshing = false;
    failedRequests = [];
  }
}
```

Gotchas:

1. Make sure you're keeping track of `DioError` and `ErrorInterceptorHandler` of each failed request, and use them to perform the retry request.
2. Make sure you set the `isRefreshing` to false after retrying all the failed requests.
3. Make sure you empty the `failedRequests` list once you're done.

Hope this solution works for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this example below, for case multiple requests, without QueuedInterceptor, and

- Only trigger call refresh token flow 01 times
- Hold all requests and retry them after performing refresh token success

```
class AuthInterceptor extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  final Dio dio;

  AuthInterceptor(this.dio);

  // when accessToken is expired & having multiple requests call
  // this variable to lock others request to make sure only trigger call refresh token 01 times
  // to prevent duplicate refresh call
  bool _isRefreshing = false;

  // when having multiple requests call at the same time, you need to store them in a list
  // then loop this list to retry every request later, after call refresh token success
  final _requestsNeedRetry = <({RequestOptions options, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler})>[];

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    final accessToken = getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage();
    options.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';
    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    final response = err.response;
    if (response != null &&
        // status code for unauthorized usually 401
        response.statusCode == 401 &&
        // refresh token call maybe fail by it self
        // eg: when refreshToken also is expired -> can't get new accessToken
        // usually server also return 401 unauthorized for this case
        // need to exlude it to prevent loop infinite call
        response.requestOptions.path != "path/your/endpoint/refresh") {
      // if hasn't not refreshing yet, let's start it
      if (!_isRefreshing) {
        _isRefreshing = true;

        // add request (requestOptions and handler) to queue and wait to retry later
        _requestsNeedRetry.add((options: response.requestOptions, handler: handler));

        // call api refresh token
        final isRefreshSuccess = await _refreshToken();

        _isRefreshing = false;

        if (isRefreshSuccess) {
          // refresh success, loop requests need retry
          for (var requestNeedRetry in _requestsNeedRetry) {
            // don't need set new accessToken to header here, because these retry
            // will go through onRequest callback above (where new accessToken will be set to header)
            final retry = await dio.fetch(requestNeedRetry.options);
            requestNeedRetry.handler.resolve(retry);
          }
          _requestsNeedRetry.clear();
        } else {
          _requestsNeedRetry.clear();
          // if refresh fail, force logout user here
        }
      } else {
        // if refresh flow is processing, add this request to queue and wait to retry later
        _requestsNeedRetry.add((options: response.requestOptions, handler: handler));
      }
    } else {
      // ignore other error is not unauthorized
      return handler.next(err);
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _refreshToken() async {
    try {
      final refreshToken = getRefreshTokenFromLocalStorage();
      final res = await callApiRefreshToken(refreshToken);
      if (res.response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("refresh token success");
        final refreshResponse = RefreshResponse.fromJson(res.data);
        // save new access + refresh token to your local storage for using later
        setAccessTokenToLocalStorage(refreshResponse.accessToken);
        setRefreshTokenToLocalStorage(refreshResponse.refreshToken);
        return true;
      } else {
        print("refresh token fail ${res.response.statusMessage ?? res.response.toString()}");
        return false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("refresh token fail $error");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I implemented a simpler solution:

1. Create a set to hold the invalid tokens.
2. Add following logic to `onError` method

- When a new invalid token is caught, not in the set, add this in the set and refresh token.
- If this token is already caught, add the fresh token to the header ( because I know I refreshed the token on the previous error ) and retry the request.

Here is a sample code, of course you may refactor and improve it, but the main reasoning is this.

```
Set<String> invalidTokens = {};


/// sample onError method:
onError: (DioException error, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (error.response?.statusCode != HttpStatus.unauthorized) {
      return handler.reject(error);
    }

    final options = error.response!.requestOptions;
    final invalidToken = error.requestOptions.headers['authorization'];
    
    /// If this token is in set, it is already caught and we already refreshed the token
    /// We change the token of the request, retry and resolve
    if (invalidTokens.contains(invalidToken)) {
      options.headers['authorization'] = "${networkService._token}";
      try {
        final retryRequest = await _retryRequest(options);
        return handler.resolve(retryRequest);
      } on DioException catch (e) {
        return handler.reject(e);
      }
    } else {
      /// We have a new invalidToken, save it, then continue to refresh token and retry
      networkService.invalidTokens.add(invalidToken);
    }

    final token = await loginService.refreshToken();
    if (token == null) {
      return handler.reject(error);
    }
    try {
      networkService.token = token;
      options.headers['authorization'] = "$token";
      final retryRequest = await _retryRequest(options);
      return handler.resolve(retryRequest);
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      return handler.reject(e);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create variable **string token**
and after that , pass this variable to  **data[token]** instead of  **(data['access_token'])**

```
late  String token ; // global variable 
var newAccessToken = refreshResponse.data[token];
```

after that , save this token in sharedprrf or any local data ,and call get save this token in main screen
This format will ensure that every application you open will refresh the token

**this set save token in button **

```
await sharedPref.setString('token' , value);
```

// value = model.accesstoken
Whatever the model looks like, the access_token parameter is visible to it

**this get token from shared pref**

```
void main()async  {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  token =  await SharededPref.get('token') ?? '';
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Please clean up the markdown and grammar to let people better understand you.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.